# How to get the grouped result with an EF query for the following data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table `Person` with firstname, last name, id. Another table with roles(string) for that person, another table with categories(string). these roles and categories are connected with Occupation table (it consists of relation between roles and categories with their foreign key reference), base table `PersonOccupation` consists of relation between `Person` and `Occupation` table

i need to search whether firstname or last name or roles or categories consist of a letter :"A",
the resultant should be

```json
{
    "Res": [
        {
            "PersonId": "1",
            "LastName": "Chris",
            "FirstName": "Angel",
            "Categories": [
                "HumanResource",
                "It professional"
            ],
            "Roles": [
                "Manager",
                "Social Activist"
            ]
        },
        {
            "PersonId": "2",
            "LastName": "Tex",
            "FirstName": "Roy",
            "Categories": [
                "HumanResource",
                "It professional"
            ],
            "Roles": [
                "Manager",
                "Social Activist"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The LINQ I used is

```cs
Context.PersonOccupation
    .Include(x => x.Occupation)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.categories)
    .Include(x => x.Occupation)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.roles)
    .Include(x => x.Person)
    .AsNoTracking();
```

What i get is

```json
{
    "Res": [
        {
            "PersonId": "1",
            "LastName": "Chris",
            "FirstName": "Angel",
            "Categories": "HumanResource"
        },
        {
            "PersonId": "1",
            "LastName": "Chris",
            "FirstName": "Angel",
            "Categories": "It professional"
        },
        {
            "PersonId": "1",
            "LastName": "Chris",
            "FirstName": "Angel",
            "Roles": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "PersonId": "1",
            "LastName": "Chris",
            "FirstName": "Angel",
            "Roles": "Social Activist"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Without the classes it's impossible to guess what's being returned, why or how to fix it. LINQ doesn't return JSON either, but if what you posted matches the results, there's no grouping in the first example. If you want *persons*, shouldn't the query start from *context.Persons*?

Comment: The "actual" results don't seem to match the query either, unless `PersonOccupation` includes a person's FirstName, LastName as well. That doesn't match what anyone would expect. Either the results come from different queries or mappings, or the classes have unexpected fields. The fact you get such flat results from such a deep query means there are no relations or, once again, what was posted isn't the real query

Comment: C# is a language of types - what are your types? Also, "consists of A" seems to match none of your expectations - please be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly, your three classes should be:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{ 
    public int RoleId { get; set;}
    public string Name {  get; set; }            
    public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }    
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

and your code, without thinking too much, could be:

```
List<Person> searchPersons = db.Persons.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains("A") || x.LastName.Contains("A")).ToList();
List<Person> searchRoles = db.Persons.Include(x => x.Roles).Where(x => x.Roles.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("A"))).ToList();
List<Person> searchCategories = db.Persons.Include(x => x.Categories).Where(x => x.Categories.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("A"))).ToList();
searchPersons.AddRange(searchRoles);
searchPersons.AddRange(searchCategories);
```

being the final result put in **searchPersons**.